# OIS swaption in python QuantLib

Tags: python, quantlib

I am working in Python using the QuantLib library to create a swaption where the underlying swap is an OIS.

```
calc_date = ql.Date(23,6,2023)
exercise_date = calendar.advance(calc_date, ql.Period('1y'))
exercise = ql.EuropeanExercise(exercise_date)
settlementType = ql.Settlement.Physical 
settlementMethod = ql.Settlement.ParYieldCurve 
underlying_swap = ql.MakeOIS(ql.Period('1y'), sofrIndex, 0.052401, nominal=notional)

swaption = ql.Swaption(underlying_swap, 0.03943, settlementType, settlementMethod)
```

But this results in the following error

```
TypeError: Wrong number or type of arguments for overloaded function 'new_Swaption'.
  Possible C/C++ prototypes are:
    Swaption::Swaption(ext::shared_ptr< VanillaSwap > const &,ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &,Settlement::Type,Settlement::Method)
    Swaption::Swaption(ext::shared_ptr< VanillaSwap > const &,ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &,Settlement::Type)
    Swaption::Swaption(ext::shared_ptr< VanillaSwap > const &,ext::shared_ptr< Exercise > const &)
```

Is it not possible to create a swaption with an OIS in QuantLib? t seems to work ok with an ordinary vanilla swap. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What does the second argument `0.03943` represent? Looks like what's expected is an instance of `EuropeanExercise`, `AmericanExercise` or `BermudanExercise`. https://quantlib-python-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/instruments/swaptions.html

Comment: Yes sorry I pasted the wrong part of the code. It was supposed to be my 'exercise' argument that is defined above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Support for OIS swaptions is underway but not yet there.  You can watch https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib/pull/1593 for news.